# Concat dictionary or variable to string

Tags: python

I would like to add a dictionary or variable to a string, instead of having the attributes, I would like to have reference to the Dict as it's dynamic and not constant.

```
Dict={
        "first_name" : "jeff",
        "gender" : "male"
    }

'"attributes": {
        "first_name" : "jeff",
        "gender" : "male"
    }'

'"attributes": Dict'
```

I tried using '"attributes": + Dict + '

Comment: please clarify with sample output

Comment: did  you tried `str(Dict)`?

Comment: Try `import json`, then `+ json.dumps(Dict) +`. You can use it further in order to set indentation in the output string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dict={
        "first_name" : "jeff",
        "gender" : "male"
    }
s="attributes: " + str(Dict)
# "attributes: {'gender': 'male', 'first_name': 'jeff'}"
```

Comment: thx but it added the str(Dict) with // from some reason:
"attributes":{\\'first_name\\': \\'jeff\\', \\'gender\\': 'male'}'